# How to set the Proxy properly in Node.js for bots that run behind a network proxy

Tags: botframework

How to set the Proxy properly for a Node.js bot that runs behind a network proxy?  The bot runs fine when not running behind the proxy but when it is run on the network with the proxy it fails.

When the proxy is set properly, will downstream calls to LUIS and QnA Maker also respect that proxy and, if not, how can the proxy be set for those separate calls

Tried running bot outside the proxied network and it runs fine. When network is switched back to the network with the proxy it fails to connect.

Answer (score 1):

This is [known issue and is currently being worked on](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/717). I'll update if workarounds are found.

Answer (score 0):

Setting HTTPS_PROXY environmental variable fixed this for me for LUIS and QnA Maker. QnA Maker was simple REST call but LUIS was using the standard connector. But both worked fine locally after making this change.

Setting HTTP_PROXY as well ended up breaking the bot, I couldn't connect at all. Not sure if that is specific to my corporate network or if the same will happen for everyone.

This didn't solve the issue for CosmosDB for me, as I assume it's using that botframework-connector that isn't respecting proxies.